# Handling MongoDB Replica Set Connection Issues when Primary Goes Down - Hosts already added

Tags: mongodb, docker, express, mongoose, docker-compose

I've set up a MongoDB replica set within Docker containers and connected it to an Express app. The setup works well under normal conditions.

However, when I simulate a failure by pausing the primary MongoDB container (**`mongo1`**), my application fails to retrieve data and throws a **`ReplicaSetNoPrimary`** error, even though one of the secondary nodes (**`mongo2`**) gets promoted to primary as expected.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

1. **MongoDB Cluster Setup**: Created a three-node MongoDB replica set using Docker. Adjusted my **`/etc/hosts`** to resolve **`mongo1`**, **`mongo2`**, and **`mongo3`** to localhost.
2. **Express App Configuration**: Used Mongoose to connect to the MongoDB cluster, specifying **`replicaSet`**, **`readPreference`**, and other connection options.
3. **Issue**: On pausing **`mongo1`**, the app's attempts to fetch data result in a **`ReplicaSetNoPrimary`** error, despite the cluster electing a new primary (**`mongo2`**).

**Error Received**:

```
{
  "reason": {
    "type": "ReplicaSetNoPrimary",
    "servers": {},
    "stale": false,
    "compatible": true,
    "heartbeatFrequencyMS": 10000,
    "localThresholdMS": 15,
    "setName": "rs0",
    "maxElectionId": "7fffffff0000000000000002",
    "maxSetVersion": 1,
    "commonWireVersion": 0,
    "logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes": null
  }
}
```

#### Primary Elections?

I confirmed that **`mongo2`** was successfully promoted to primary. Yet, the app does not seem to recognize the new primary and fails to perform read operations.[image]

Could anyone help me understand why the application fails to connect to the new primary after **`mongo1`** goes down and how to ensure seamless failover in such scenarios?

### Steps to repo:

MongoDB Replica Set Setup in Docker

1. **Create a Docker network:**

   ```
   docker network create mongoCluster
   ```
2. **Run MongoDB containers:**

   ```
   docker run -d --rm -p 27017:27017 --name mongo1 --network mongoCluster mongo:latest mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo1
   ```

   ```
   docker run -d --rm -p 27018:27017 --name mongo2 --network mongoCluster mongo:latest mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo2
   ```

   ```
   docker run -d --rm -p 27019:27017 --name mongo3 --network mongoCluster mongo:latest mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo3
   ```
3. **Initiate the replica set:**

   ```
   docker exec -it mongo1 mongosh --eval "rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', members: [{_id: 0, host: 'mongo1'}, {_id: 1, host: 'mongo2'}, {_id: 2, host: 'mongo3'}]})"
   ```
4. **Update `/etc/hosts` (Optional for name resolution):**

   Add entries for **`mongo1`**, **`mongo2`**, and **`mongo3`** pointing to **`127.0.0.1`**.

Express Application Setup

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Mongoose connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27018,mongo3:27019/mydb", {
  replicaSet: "rs0",
  readPreference: "nearest",
  w: "majority",
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => console.log("Connected to DB"))
  .catch(err => console.error("DB connection error:", err));

// Define a schema and model
const Person = mongoose.model("Person", new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, age: Number }));

// Example route
app.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  Person.find()
    .then(persons => res.send(persons))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

#### Testing Failover

1. **Continuously fetch data:**
   Use a simple loop to call route:

   ```
   while true; do
     curl --location 'http://localhost:3000/all'
     echo "\n"
     sleep 1
   done
   ```
2. **Simulate primary node failure:**

   Pause the primary container (e.g., **`docker pause mongo1`**) and observe the application's response.

#### Expected Outcome

- The MongoDB cluster should automatically elect a new primary among the remaining nodes (**`mongo2`** or **`mongo3`**).
- The Express application, after a short period of adjustment, should continue to serve requests by connecting to the new primary.